# 74HC540 vs 7404

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, relay, power-electronics

Iam relatively new to electronics, and I am building a prototype from an Arduino board. I see that I can control a relay from an Arduino.

However the problem is - the relay I am using is active low. So I decided to use a inverter - ICIC7404. But in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39920/turn-on-a-relay-when-the-output-is-high) they are suggesting to use a 74HC540. Does it make any difference? Can i use a 7404 instead of 74HC540?

Comment: What are the differences between 7404 and 74HC540 that you can read out of the datasheet? Do they matter for your purpose?

Comment: The HC540 and CD74HCT540 are Inverting Octal Buffers
and Line Drivers with Three-State Outputs and the capability
to drive 15 LSTTL loads. I dont understand what this means.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to invert the signal already in your software? Means to actively drive the pin for the inactive state instead of using a separate inverter?

Comment: I am using a led to show the status of the pin. So when I am active high, the led turns on. But the relay is off. So i was thinking of using an inverter.

Comment: As @Humpawumpa says, invert the logic in your code.  Also move the LED to be active LOW by connecting the anode to the + supply via a resistor and switch the cathode.

Comment: @bukkehariprasad Are you merely wanting the LED to turn on when the relay is on? That's it? Just use two resistors, and a BJT to invert the signal to the LED. Or else a resistor and mosfet for the LED. No need for an IC package.

Comment: @jonk : i have 8 such relays, so i thought of using an IC package instead of a BJT.

Comment: @HandyHowie : thanks for the idea. I haven't searched about this. I will surely try this. :)

Comment: @bukkehariprasad Oh. Sorry. If you decide to stay with an inverter in an IC package rather than using other pins or changing the logic of the pins you have, then look at the \$I_\text{OH}\$ and \$I_\text{OL}\$ specifications. These will tell you some details about how much current they can handle. Your LED will probably look okay if you wire it so that you use an active-LO arrangement (ON) because the low output usually has higher drive ability. Don't forget to use a current limit resistor, too.

Comment: @jonk : Okay. I will check it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LED consumes little current so is not an issue. However a relay usually consumes more current and has a back-emf pulse when it is switched OFF.

This diagram should solve the problem. No need to install a bulky IC. Also, Vcc does NOT have to be the same as the Arduino power pin. The relay can be from 3.3 volt to 12 volts. If LED is too bright, increase R3 to 1 K.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMqUxZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A link to the ULN2803:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution works when there is a single relay. I am using a set of 8 relays. So isnt considering an IC the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need a ULN2803 8 Darlington relay driver. It is an 18 pin DIP IC. It is like the circuit I drew up but has 8 of them in one package.

Comment: I will check it for sure. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I left you a present. It should work fine.